# R - modifying values columns depending on strings in same row

Tags: r, string, dataframe

I am super new to R, so sorry to bother you with such a simple question.
I have a large data frame (full one has 25 columns & several million rows) containing information for a peptide spectral library (see example below).
I am introducing modifications into the base library by writing their abbreviations (UniMod:XXX) into the peptide sequences (PeptideSequence). All I have left is updating the peptide masses (PrecursorMz) in accordance to the occurrence of my modifications and the charge (PrecursorCharge). So for each "(UniMod:259)" partial string I would have to increase the corresponding mass by 8 (10 for (UniMod:267), divided by the charge (charge is NOT always 3, sorry). E.g. modified first line should read 714.64876 after factoring in the modifications in the sequence.

`PrecursorMz   PeptideSequence                              PrecursorCharge
 709.31543     AAAEK(UniMod:259)LFGNMEGDCPSDWK(UniMod:259)  3
 709.31543     AAAEKLFGNMEGDCPSDWK(UniMod:259)              3
 529.58044     AK(UniMod:259)LWCSTTADYDR(UniMod:267)        3`

Thank you so much and will provide and additional info you might need.

Comment: What if `PeptideSequence` contains both `UniMod:259` and `UniMod:267` (like in line 3) ? What should be done in that case? Do you only have these 2 values? Can you show your expected output for given data?

Comment: in this case, PrecursorMz should increase by (8 + 10)/3. For this library, I only have these two values new values. THere are some other UniMod:XXX strings in the library, but these are already taken into account as they are pretty common.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `stringr::str_count` from `stringr` (part of `tidyverse`)

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
map_if(is.factor, as.character) %>%
  mutate(
    PrecursorMz = PrecursorMz + (
      8 * str_count(PeptideSequence, "UniMod:259") + 10 * str_count(PeptideSequence, "UniMod:267")
    ) / PrecursorCharge,
    PrecursorMz = format(round(PrecursorMz, 5), nsmall = 5)
  )
# A tibble: 3 x 3
  PrecursorMz PeptideSequence                             PrecursorCharge
  <chr>       <chr>                                                 <dbl>
1 714.64876   AAAEK(UniMod:259)LFGNMEGDCPSDWK(UniMod:259)               3
2 711.98210   AAAEKLFGNMEGDCPSDWK(UniMod:259)                           3
3 535.58044   AK(UniMod:259)LWCSTTADYDR(UniMod:267)                     3
```

Comment: Dear Greg, thanks for your input. When I try out your solution after installing tidyverse, I get the two error message of In Ops.factor((8 * str_count(PeptideSequence, "UniMod:259") + 10 *  :  ‘/’ not meaningful for factors. I also tried to convert my data frame into a tibble but get the same result.

Comment: @JWL I added  `map_if(is.factor, as.character)` which should convert  between `factor` and `character`.  If you're making your dataframe with `data.frame` you can also set `stringsAsFactors = FALSE`